# try-finally with SqlAlchemy: is this a good habit?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, with-statement

I'm used to do this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

Session = sessionmaker()
engine = create_engine("some connection db string", echo=False)
Session.configure(bind=engine)

db_con = Session()

try:
    # DB MANIPULATION
finally:
    db_con.close()
```

Is this a good habit? If so, why sqlalchemy does not permit you to do simply:

```
with Session() as db_con:
    # DB MANIPULATION
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't good practice. It's easy to forget, and will make the code more confusing.

Instead, you can use the `contextlib.closing` context manager, and make that the only way to get a session.

```
# Wrapped in a custom context manager for better readability
@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_session():
    with contextlib.closing(Session()) as session:
        yield session

with get_session() as session:
    session.add(...)
```

Comment: I did not know `contextlib`. The code is really clean. But about the second part of the question, why `sqlalchemy`'s `Session()` object does not have a `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` builtin methods, in your opinion?

Comment: @MarcoSulla I don't have an opinion on it. Probably it's because `closing` exists. Ask the devs

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you are done with the session object you should close the session. **session.close** will return the connection back to engine pool and if you are exiting the program you should dispose the engine pool with **engine.dispose**.

Now to your question. In most cases sessions will be used on long running applications like web server. Where it makes sense to centralize the session management. For example in [flask-sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) session is created with start of each web-request and closed when the request of over.

Comment: What if you have not exclusive access to the database?

Comment: I am not sure how exclusive access of database comes into picture. As long you have access to the database, you can create a **engine** object and hence a connection pool.

Comment: Pooling is interesting, but I think you misunderstood its use: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html - as you can read, pool is created by the engine, and there's already a pooling mechanism by default. Simply, db_con.close() does not really dispose the connection, but returns it to the pool. On the contrary you would create a session and use it all the time, which is not a good idea if connection is dropped or if your database is shared and simultaneous connections are limited, so you can't connect and stay, because you'll be fired after two minutes.